# $X=\{1,2,3\}$, which kind of topology on $X$ can be induced by a metric?

Tags: general-topology

The question starts from a common quiz:

Given $(X,\tau)$, where $X$ is $\{1, 2, 3\},\tau$ is the indiscrete topology (Only $X$ and $\emptyset$), and the question is the existence of a metric which can induce this topology.
I don't think this kind of metric exist, for $\{1\}$ will be open. (If not wrong)

So I start to consider, which kind of topology of $X$ can be induced by a metric?
Just as $\tau=\{X,\emptyset,\{1\}\}$，or other patterns?

Comment: all metric spaces are $T_2$ spaces meaning you can separate points with disjoint open sets. The only $T_2$ topology on any finite set is the discrete one which is induced by the discrete metric  (the distance between two points is zero if they are the same and 1 if they are different)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that the trivial topology is not metrizable on this set.  A metric space is always Hausdorff, for instance, so if the underlying set is finite we get a discrete space.

Answer (score 2):

Given any  set $X$, containing at least two (distinct) elements, the function $d:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$d(x,y)=1\ \ \hbox{if $x\neq y$}$$
$$d(x,x)=0 \ \ \forall x\in X$$
is a metric inducing the discrete topology.

Answer (score 1):

In a metric topology any set of the form $\{x\}$ is closed. So if $\mathcal{T}$ is a metric topology on $X$, a finite set, any subset of $X$ is finite, and so closed ( as a finite union of singletons), and so any subset of $X$ is open too. It follows that $\mathcal{T}=\mathscr{P}(X)$, the discrete topology. This topology is indeed induced by the so-called discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq y$, so a metric topology on $\{1,2,3\}$ can only be the discrete topology.